# Moching rails association methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, mocha.js, testunit

Here is my helper method which I want to test.

```
def posts_correlation(name)    
  if name.present?      
    author = User.find_by_name(name)
    author.posts.count * 100 / Post.count if author  
  end
end
```

A factory for user.

```
factory :user do
  email 'user@example.com'
  password 'secret'
  password_confirmation { password }
  name 'Brian'    
end
```

And finally a test which permanently fails.

```
test "should calculate posts count correlation" do
  @author = FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: 'Jason')

  @author.posts.expects(:count).returns(40)
  Post.expects(:count).returns(100)

  assert_equal 40, posts_correlation('Jason')
end
```

Like this.

```
UsersHelperTest:
  FAIL should calculate posts count correlation (0.42s) 
       <40> expected but was <0>.
  test/unit/helpers/users_helper_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:UsersHelperTest>'
```

And the whole problem is that mocha doesn't really mock the count value of author's posts, and it returns 0 instead of 40.

Are there any better ways of doing this: `@author.posts.expects(:count).returns(40)` ?

Comment: what if you do: `author.stubs(:posts).returns(stub(:count => 40))`. That said, stub_chains are much better handled in Rspec

Answer (score 1):

When your helper method runs, it's retrieving its own object reference to your author, not the @author defined in the test. If you were to `puts @author.object_id` and `puts author.object_id` in the helper method, you would see this problem.

A better way is to pass the setup data for the author in to your mocked record as opposed to setting up expectations on the test object.

It's been a while since I used FactoryGirl, but I think something like this should work:

```
@author = FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: 'Jason')
(1..40).each { |i| FactoryGirl.create(:post, user_id: @author.id ) }
```

Not terribly efficient, but should at least get the desired result in that the data will actually be attached to the record.

Comment: This will work, yes. But I'd prefer to do it more with mocha, without creating 40 extra records in database. Is there a way?

Comment: I also tried to add this line to my test `User.expects(:find_by_name).with(anything).returns(@author)` but it didn't help to pass.

Comment: That's because when it calls @author.posts, posts will again be a different object to the one mocked in the test. If you need to mock anything, give @author a mock posts object, like `@author.expects(:posts).returns(['dummy']*40)` instead of mocking the calls to the posts object.